# Electron - Can't initialize program

Tags: javascript, electron

I followed a few video tutorials (such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RL305ldfzm8) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mr9Mtm_TRpw)), which use a very similar code, which throws up an error.

My files:
package.json

```
{
  "name": "steamcmd-gui",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "avi12",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.7.5"
  }
}
```

main.js

```
const electron = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

let win;

function createWindow() {
    win = new electron.BrowserWindow();
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
        protocol: "file",
        slashes: true
    });
);

win.on("closed", () => win = null);    

electron.app.on("ready", createWindow);

electron.app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
        app.quit();
    }
});
```

When trying to execute `main.js`, the debugger throws:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\avi12\OneDrive\Documents\WebStorm\SteamCMD GUI\main.js:18:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Which means that `electron.app` is `undefined` for some reason.
Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: how did you run main.js ?

Comment: I'm using JetBrains WebStorm to edit my files, and it has a few execution options - I picked Node js and specified `main.js` there.

Comment: Install electron, then run it using `electron main.js`

Comment: @PeterMader That was a nice solution! But, how can I run it using `electron .` then?

Comment: i assume you have installed electron already otherwise you should get errors before this error.

Comment: Thanks for leading me to the answer! I answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Fast Snail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227526/fast-snail), who realized that I should execute my `main.js` using `electron main.js` - I looked up in Google for a solution and found [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/05/getting-started-with-electron-in-webstorm/) very nice tutorial, which solved my problem.

The thing was that I had to specify some extra configurations in order to execute my script using Electron, from JetBrains WebStorm.
Thanks a lot!